# Styled Base UI component with parameter throws TypeScript error

Tags: reactjs, typescript, material-ui, base-ui

This tsx code:

```
import React from "react";
import BaseButton from "@mui/base/Button";
import styled from "@emotion/styled";

export const enum BUTTON_TYPE {
  MAIN = "main",
  LINK = "link",
}

const Button = ({
  text,
  type,
}: {
  text: string;
  type: BUTTON_TYPE;
}) => {
  return (
    <StyledButton type={type}>
      {text}
    </StyledButton>
  );
};

const getBorderColor = (type: BUTTON_TYPE): string => {
  if(type === BUTTON_TYPE.MAIN) {
    return "#abcabc";
  }
  else {
    return "#cbacba";
  }
};

const StyledButton = styled(BaseButton)<{
  type: BUTTON_TYPE;
}>`
  border: 1px solid ${({ type }) => getBorderColor(type)};
`;

export default Button;
```

Throws this error:

```
src/modules/Button/Button.tsx:18:6 - error TS2745: This JSX tag's 'children' prop 
expects type 'never' which requires multiple children, but only a single child was 
provided.

18     <StyledButton type={type}>
    ~~~~~~~~~~~~

src/modules/Button/Button.tsx:18:19 - error TS2322: Type 
'import("C:/ez/DS13/src/modules/Button/Button2").BUTTON_TYPE' is not assignable to type 
'never'.

18     <StyledButton type={type}>
```

What type change could fix the error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The main issue is that your `type` prop of type `BUTTON_TYPE` conflicts with the `type` prop of `<button>` which has a type of `"button" | "submit" | "reset"`. In the working example below, I have fixed it by using a different prop name of `variant` for that purpose on `StyledButton`. The `Button` type that is exported in your code still retains the `type` prop name, so usage would be the same as in your code.

```
import * as React from "react";
import BaseButton from "@mui/base/Button";
import styled from "@emotion/styled";

export const enum BUTTON_TYPE {
  MAIN = "main",
  LINK = "link"
}
const getBorderColor = (type: BUTTON_TYPE): string => {
  if (type === BUTTON_TYPE.MAIN) {
    return "#abcabc";
  } else {
    return "#cbacba";
  }
};

const StyledButton = styled(BaseButton, {
  shouldForwardProp: (propName) => propName !== "variant"
})<{ variant: BUTTON_TYPE }>`
  border: 1px solid ${({ variant }) => getBorderColor(variant)};
`;
const Button = ({ text, type }: { text: string; type: BUTTON_TYPE }) => {
  return <StyledButton variant={type}>{text}</StyledButton>;
};

export default function Demo() {
  return (
    <>
      <Button type={BUTTON_TYPE.MAIN} text="Hello" />
      <Button type={BUTTON_TYPE.LINK} text="World" />
    </>
  );
}
```

[image: Edit base Button customization]

Comment: Resolving the prop conflict worked. I'm wondering, why the error message indicated a different reason.

Comment: The original message was saying it conflicted with type `never` which indicates that `type` was typed in a way that can never be satisfied -- it can't be both `BUTTON_TYPE` and one of `"button" | "submit" | "reset"`.